# VBA - Outlook Not Removing Attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing a macro that should remove attachments. From my debugging sessions, it appears as if it should work. The breakpoint is hit and it recognizes the message object:

[image]

I know this sounds a bit silly, but, oddly enough, it seems to work if I set a breakpoint, and open the expression/watch, but not otherwise.

I have been struggling with this for quite some time; I would appreciate any guidance.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

 Dim header As String
 Dim objNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Item As Object
Dim count As Integer


    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim entryIDs
    entryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(entryIDs)
        Set objNewMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(entryIDs(i))
                If objNewMail.Attachments.count > 0 Then
                    header = GetHeader(objNewMail)
                If DoesIPMatch(header) <> True Then
                   DeleteMessage (objNewMail)
                ElseIf IsAttachmentPDF(objNewMail) <> True Then
                     For count = 1 To objNewMail.Attachments.count
                       objNewMail.Attachments.Remove (count)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but the parentheses around `(count)` are redundant. `objNewMail.Attachments.Remove count` should be sufficient. `count` doesn't need to be evaluated and passed by value (that's what the extra parens do)... it's *already* a value.

Comment: Thanks! I am not a VBA person (more of a C# gal), so I definitely appreciate the observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, as a most likely culprit if you are removing items from a collection it should always be done in reverse order, otherwise you have to re-index your counter variable, and that makes for messy code:

It may also be necessary to Save the `objNewMail` item after you've modified it (e.g., by removing attachments)

```
For count = objNewMail.Attachments.count to 1 Step - 1
    objNewMail.Attachments.Remove count
Next
objNewMail.Save '## Not sure if this is necessary
```

Alternatively:

```
With objNewMail.Attachments
    While .Count > 0
        .Remove 1
    Wend
End With
objNewMail.Save
```

Comment: Wow, I do not know if it was removing the () around count, reversing the order of the loop, or calling save, but this worked. I have been fighting with for so long, so a sincere thank-you.

Comment: It's probably the `Save` that fixed it. I look at your screenshot and the example item only has 1 attachment, so the sort wouldn't be affected in that case, only if there are 2 or more attachments.